# Weird undefined index: id,std notices. How to fix it?

Tags: theme-options, debug

Ok I'm running my wordpress in debug mode. I'm getting lot of notices.

This is my code.

```
<?php
//allows the theme to get info from the theme options page
global $options;
foreach ($options as $value) {
    if (get_option( $value['id'] ) === FALSE) { $$value['id'] = $value['std']; }
    else { $$value['id'] = get_option( $value['id'] ); }
    }
?>
```

This is what i'm seeing.

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in functions\get-options.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: std in functions\get-options.php on line 5
```

These notices repeated around 20 times. 
Whats wrong in my code?. Can anyone help me to fix those errors. Thanks.

Comment: post the code that sets `$options`

Comment: @Bainternet [Here is my `$options` code](http://pastebin.com/yGaN0v1W)

Comment: Oh dear! get-options.php has an std!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Write `false === get_option( 'whatever' );` - [see Coding Standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards).

Second: Why do you have a variable-variable in there? `$$value['id'] = $value['std'];`.

Comment: Hey thanks bro, Well i didn't code that theme. I'm just using that theme. Can you look in to [this code](http://pastebin.com/yGaN0v1W)? You may get some ideas why it coded in that way. Thanks

Comment: My IDE says, there are no errors or typos. Anyway: What does this have to do with the code shown above or my Q? It's a simple mulitdimensional array.

Comment: No, I gave you [this code](http://pastebin.com/yGaN0v1W) because @Bainternet said that there is a bug in the code that sets `$options`.  [This is the code](http://pastebin.com/yGaN0v1W) that sets `$options`

Comment: Please avoid linking code more than once. This only creates confusion. Always update your Q with relevant info when something changes. Further: I checked the code (you linked) with my IDE (Eclipse) and found no errors, so your problem is not in there. Also: You didn't mention from where exactly your above code is. Is thist the code from get-option.php?, or what else? Go back and update the Q and be as specific and detailed as possible. Currently it's a chaos and fishing in the dark.